# how to add welcome screen message with image in Facebook messenger at the top?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, chatbot, facebook-messenger-bot, facebook-chatbot

I have a very simple chatbot in messenger, I have added a welcome screen and get started button

Now I would like to add an image at the top like this here

[image]

I am using samples codes from facebook

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{
  "greeting": [
    {
      "locale":"default",
      "text":"Hello!" 
    }, {
      "locale":"en_US",
      "text":"Timeless apparel for the masses."
    }
  ]
}' "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messenger_profile?access_token=<PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN>"
```

What do I need to change to get what I want ???

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/discovery/welcome-screen

Answer (score 0):

The round circle image comes from the Facebook Page Profile photo. And the square shaped image on the back comes from Facebook Page Cover photo. Change those images and you will see these photos changed as well.